# some features of KDE Connect don't work

Tags: kde, kde-connect

I'm trying to get KDE Connect (version 1.4.0) to work at full capacity with my Android phone and Feren OS (UbuntuLTS+LinuxMint+KDE).

Pairing, exchange of notifications, and even such a cute feature as pausing PC music player during outgoing/incoming phone calls work perfectly.

However, when it comes to the menu items, only "Ring my phone" works.
**"Share file" and "SMS Messages" don't do anything at all.**

As for **"Browse this device"** (or clicking my phone shown under "Devices" in Dolphin sidebar), first there was a problem with the `deviceID` folder automatically created under `/run/user/1000` which showed no owner, etc. resulting in an error message like inaccessible or unavailable or permissions problem. When I managed to create a folder with no ownership/permissions problems, I then received another error message: `Error when accessing filesystem.sshfs Finished with exit code 1`